# Post getting down-votes, because it's a duplicate. Can't delete.

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, deletion

I posted a question regarding a ["new discovery" with divisibility tests](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3440274/divisibility-by-7-test-7-mid-10ba-iff-7-mid-b5a) and it was marked as duplicate by a user because it is very similar to other divisibility tests. I am losing reputation because of this, and would like it deleted, but have no control over the question.

I feel this is very unfair. Recently, SO/SE proclaimed they are "celebrating question askers" but this feels like a punishment.

Can something be implemented to give askers of questions a littler more control?

edit: I also literally do not care about my Meta reputation, so keep down-voting at will.

[image]

Comment: You've got three upvotes and one downvote.  You're up 28 points.  You would have been up 13 points before the change.  I'm sorry someone has a bee in their bonnet about asking a question before searching, I suppose, but I'm not seeing the harm done to you here.

Comment: @MatthewDaly I did not ask for upvotes. I asked for the question to be deleted. The referenced question has not been posted.

Comment: "I also literally do not care about my Meta reputation, so keep down-voting at will." -- Upvotes and downvotes on Meta do not affect your reputation (it's more a statement about agreement or reasonableness or whatever the context dictates), in order to encourage discussion and, at minimum, giving an opinion. Or at least that's my take.

Comment: Regarding your comment on your "meta reputation":  (1) there is no meta distinct meta reputation (at least, not one that is displayed---I believe that there is a "hidden" meta rep which dictates whether or not you can ask / answer questions, but this isn't user-viewable), and votes on meta don't affect your rep.  Indeed, votes on meta mean something different---an upvote means "I agree with this proposal / comment / complaint / etc", while a downvote means "I disagree."  In this case, the downvotes likely mean "I don't think that there is an issue here."

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "The referenced question has not been posted". The question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3444466/why-does-chika-ofilis-method-for-checking-divisibility-for-7-work was closed as a duplicate of yours. That appears to be the reason why you can't delete your question. In the present case, this strikes me as an unintended consequence of the way stackexchange has written its software. It may be worth raising the problem here with a new question, or perhaps contacting moderators directly about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is marked as duplicate, but this might not be the reason why you are getting a down-vote.

As pointed out in the comment, you have a net gain of reputation point, so in terms of reputation points, you are not being punished.

Yes you cannot delete your post, not because it is marked as duplicate. You cannot do that since there are upvoted answers to your questions. Check out [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) about deletion (see the remark).

I think it is clear that when someone answered your question, you are not the sole owner of the question anymore (indeed you never are). If you delete your question you also delete all the answers.

If you really want it to be deleted (see remark 2), you can post a suggestion in [CRUDE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2165/crude) chat room, and users with the deletion privilege might considering casting the delete vote (But your question is not of low quality and has already five answers, so I don't see why it should be deleted).

**Remark**: Let me just copy the relevant information in the link:

When can't I delete my own post?

Special note: You can't delete your own post using the Android app. You can, however, delete your post by using the app's option to open the question in a Web browser and deleting it from there, provided none of the below apply.

You can't delete your own answer if it has been accepted.

You can't delete your own question if it:

- has an answer with upvotes (even if that answer has a net zero or negative score)
- has an accepted answer
- has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)
- has an answer with an awarded bounty

You can't delete any of your questions or answers if you haven't registered your account (that is, associated a Google, Facebook, or Stack Exchange account with it).

Note: if you're a moderator, you can delete your own post even if it wouldn't ordinarily be allowed.

**Remark 2** That does not work either as your question is a duplicate target of another question.

Comment: I down-voted your answer as it is incorrect. The reason why I could not delete was "You cannot delete this post because it has been marked as a duplicate and referenced by another post". The fact that it *now* has positive votes is irrelevant to my original question here.

Comment: I was the one who upvoted the answers. As a test, I edited (placed a space character only) and down-voted them all of them, and could still not delete the question. I have since re-upvoted them. I will edit the OP, and you can see my error message.

Comment: I have made an edit (I think the link about deletion say very clear when you cannot delete your question. Please read them) @DavidPeterson

Comment: That is, even if it is not marked as duplicate, it cannot be deleted.

Comment: Okay, I will change my vote. Still disagree with the negative impact on the user who actually cares and tried to post a good question

Comment: At least you can ask ( went ~80+ days without that allowance here). Some may rather you didn't at this point, but I'll let them deal with that.